# how to alter enum type column in migration in testing laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, testing, phpunit

assuming that I have a code that is running on production and because of this, I can not alter the same migration file for adding new columns, like bellow

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('token_key')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->enum('type', ['avatar', 'image', 'video'])->comment(implode(', ', ['avatar', 'image', 'video']));
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

and after the first release, I want to remove `avatar` value from the column named `type` acceptable values, So I add a new migration file for adding my new column like below

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class ChangeEnumOnUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        $sql = sprintf(
            "ALTER TABLE %s CHANGE `%s` `%s` ENUM('%s') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT '%s'",
            'users',
            'type',
            'type',
            implode('\',\'', ['image', 'video']),
            implode(',', ['image', 'video'])
        );
        DB::statement($sql);
    }
}
```

and using `vendor/bin/phpunit` i run my test

> please attention that first of all database will get migrated and  because of that test method does not getting started

And SQLite is throwing error like below.

The SQLite exception is like

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "CHANGE": syntax error

Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "CHANGE": syntax error (SQL: ALTER TABLE users CHANGE `type` `type` ENUM('image','video') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'image,video')
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Without the details this is going to be a hard question to help with. Adding the contents of the second migration would be of great input. Is there anything you have tried to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have searched and found this solution, hope to be useful.

my problem was database's behavior and supporting of keys, when you use laravel's migration functionalities for changing an `enum` type you must first add `doctrine/dbal` package to your project

```
 composer require doctrine/dbal
```

then you must add `enum` type to doctrine because laravel is using the package to manipulate tables column and this laravel did not add `enum` type to the doctrine by default so __construct method in your altering migration is needed like below

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\StringType;

public function __construct()
{
    if (! Type::hasType('enum')) {
        Type::addType('enum', StringType::class);
    }
    DB::getDoctrineSchemaManager()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');
}
```

then you can change your `enum` column like below

```
$table->enum('type', ['avatar', 'video'])
      ->comment(implode(', ', ['avatar', 'video']))
      ->change();
```

and know there is no problem on change an enum type field on testing.

**ATTENTION**:
this solution is one of the offered solutions for `ENUM` types on [doctrine project's site](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/cookbook/mysql-enums.html), and it offers two solutions, the first one is `Mapping to varchars` and the second one is `Defining a custom type for enum`

If the above solution did not work for you, then you can read more about this issue and how to **solve it** in [doctrine project's site](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/cookbook/mysql-enums.html) your self

Comment: This does not work - the migration will run successfully, but your column (in my experience) is cast to varchar from enum. That is not the intended behavior

Comment: @sudoyum thank's for commenting, I did add the doctrine project's site for more solvations to the solution, the site clearly illustrates the problem and solutions, I hope this solution be useful for you

Answer (score 0):

You may not use `DB::statement` and your `sprintf` to modify your field.

So you may use the built-in function `change` of Laravel migration mechanism like that:

```php
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('name', 50)->change(); // update the field by increasing the max allowed characters
});
```

**See: [Laravel Migration: Modifying Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#modifying-columns)**